# How to point to C header files in GO?

Tags: go, include, header-files, hdf5

New to GoLang so go easy on me.  I installed this package for which are GO bindings for the HDF5s filesystem:

```
go get github.com/sbinet/go-hdf5
```

and I get

```
fatal error: hdf5.h: No such file or directory
// #include "hdf5.h"
```

the file hdf5.h (which comes from the original hdfs library, not the go package) is located in

usr/include/hdf5s/series

how do I tell the go compiler to look in the /user/include/hdf5s/series directory for this header file?

Comment: It may be a typo but `/usr != /user` `usr` stands for universal system resources.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pass the `-I` flag to the C compiler using the `CGO_CFLAGS` environment variable ([documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/)):

```
CGO_CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/hdf5s/series" go get -u github.com/sbinet/go-hdf5
```

Comment: this worked, but now im getting

# github.com/sbinet/go-hdf5

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5_hl


collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status 'code'

Comment: @BromQuinn: You may need to add the path to the library: `CGO_CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/hdf5s/series -L/usr/library path..." go get -u github.com/sbinet/go-hdf5`

Comment: Does Golang use `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai it does

Comment: You can use CGO_LDFLAGS to specify the location of the library.